# File and Directory error on running an existing python program after installation of new Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I reinstalled Windows 10 on my PC and aslo reinstalled python and VSC. The user name of my Computer is changed. Before, it was "Grace" and now it's "Adnan".
Now when I run my existing python file (that I had created before reinstalling windows 10 and python), I get "no such File or Directory error" for images I had called inside the program.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a hard-coded filepath in the code? Have you tried updating it?

Comment: @JeffUK it's like PhotoImage( file = 'Images/picture.gif'). When I tried to concatenate it with the full directory name using f"{os.getcwd}\Images/picture.gif", still it shows error, no such file or Directory.

Comment: did you try a) to use absolute paths b) relative path to the python module using os.path.dirname(__file__)

Comment: @Raphael Can you elaborate your answer please?

Answer (score 1):

as a first attempt, I recommend using absolute paths to ensure that the paths themselves are correct. That means that you relace all occurrences of relative paths (like `subfolder\myfile.txt`) with their absolute paths (`C:\Users\user\scripts\subfolder\myfile.txt`)

for relative paths, there are several options. One is to use `__file__` which is the path of the python file itself. You can then use `os.path.dirname` to get the path of the folder which contains the python file and `os.join` to append a relative path.

```
import os.path

python_file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.join(python_file_dir, 'subfolder', 'myfile.txt')
```

---

example values:

```
__file__: C:\Users\user\scripts\script.py
python_file_dir: C:\Users\user\scripts
file_path: C:\Users\user\scripts\subfolder\myfile.txt
```

Comment: How to use absolute paths?

Comment: I added an example